# How to calculate statistical significance of correlation in pandas or some other python module

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, significance

I am using the Pandas library in Python.

So, I am calculating correlations between attributes in my data-set.

```
df.corr()
```

This is a nice function that returns a data-frame of correlations between all attributes.

There is this term called statistical significance of correlation, which test the probability that this difference was obtain by chance [(description here)](http://janda.org/c10/Lectures/topic06/L24-significanceR.htm).

So does anybody know if there is a function to return this in pandas or in some other Python library.

Comment: There are a number of libraries that can calculate statistical significance - `statsmodels` and `scipy`, for example.  There is ample documentation for each of those libraries available online.  But as it is currently written, your question is not really specific enough.  Why not google around for available libraries, then try one out, and if you can't get the implementation to work, write a more specific post detailing the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint I will try statsmodel and scipy and come back.