# Calculating correlations and its statistical significance with scipy.stats and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, correlation, significance

I am using the Pandas library for some data analysis. I am testing correlations between attributes. So I calculated the correlations using the `.corr()` function of the Pandas library. I also want to calculate the statistical significance of this correlations. I already asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569099/how-to-calculate-statistical-significance-of-correlation-in-pandas-or-some-other). The Pandas library seems to not have this function.

I was advised to use `scipy.stats`.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
```

`pearsonr` is the function to compute pearson correlation, which is exactly what `.corr()` except that it also returns the significance, which is what I am after for.

The `pearsonr` cannot deal with Na/null values. So I get rid of them using `.dropna()` . This removes more examples then it should.

In my original csv file there is more words for NA/ null values, I account for this when I open the file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(player, sep=',', na_values=['Did Not Dress','Did Not Play','Inactive','Not With Team'], index_col=0)
```

.corr() deals with missing the missing values itself. The question is why does the `.dropna()` remove too many examples. Some values are 0 or 0.00(percentage), but that should not be excluded for my purpose.

A few lines from the .csv file:

```
Rk,G,Date,Age,Tm,,Opp,,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG%,3P,3PA,3P%,FT,FTA,FT%,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc,+/-
1,1,2017-10-18,32-091,SAS,,MIN,W (+8),1,38:49,9,21,.429,1,2,.500,6,7,.857,5,5,10,4,0,2,3,2,25,18.9,+15
2,2,2017-10-21,32-094,SAS,@,CHI,W (+10),1,32:46,12,24,.500,0,2,.000,4,4,1.000,5,5,10,3,1,2,1,2,28,23.7,+13
3,3,2017-10-23,32-096,SAS,,TOR,W (+4),1,36:17,7,16,.438,0,1,.000,6,7,.857,3,5,8,3,1,1,2,3,20,15.4,+10
4,4,2017-10-25,32-098,SAS,@,MIA,W (+17),1,38:09,12,20,.600,1,1,1.000,6,7,.857,1,6,7,1,2,1,2,4,31,23.7,+16
5,5,2017-10-27,32-100,SAS,@,ORL,L (-27),1,29:30,9,14,.643,1,2,.500,5,5,1.000,4,7,11,0,0,1,1,0,24,22.4,-20
6,6,2017-10-29,32-102,SAS,@,IND,L (-3),1,36:24,10,21,.476,1,2,.500,5,7,.714,3,5,8,0,0,1,1,3,26,16.6,-15
7,7,2017-10-30,32-103,SAS,@,BOS,L (-14),1,26:00,5,13,.385,0,2,.000,1,5,.200,3,2,5,2,1,1,1,1,11,6.7,-19
8,8,2017-11-02,32-106,SAS,,GSW,L (-20),1,35:54,8,22,.364,2,4,.500,6,8,.750,5,5,10,2,2,2,2,3,24,17.6,-15
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to extract the two columns between which you want to compute Pearson's correlation coefficient and use Numpy isnan function to remove null values.

```
x = data.column_1.values
y = data.column_2.values
mask = ~numpy.isnan(x) * ~numpy.isnan(y)
x, y = x[M), y[M]
rvalue, pvalue = scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)
```

Prior to that you could exclude some rows based on what values they have on other columns.